# error: initializer element is not computable at load time

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I keep getting the compiler error: initializer element is not computable at load time.

I am using MPLAB C30 compiler. In other code this error was solved by having the 10 within the brackets of the array declaration but for some reason, that doesn't work here.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

```
KEYDEF KDEF_scrn00_Home[10] =
{
//Value, Action,               Link
    {0, KACT_Power,  0 } // key # 
   ,{0, KACT_GotoScreen, (void *) &SCRN_scrn01_Zone1} // key # 1
   ,{0, KACT_None,  0 } // key # 2
   ,{0, KACT_None,  0 } // key # 3
   ,{0, KACT_GotoScreen, (void *) &SCRN_scrn06_mode} // key # 4
   ,{0, KACT_GotoScreen, (void *) &SCRN_scrn04_ice} // key # 5
   ,{0, KACT_None,  0 } // key # 6
   ,{0, KACT_GotoScreen, (void *) &SCRN_scrn08_alarm} // key # 7
   ,{0, KACT_None,  0 } // key # 8
   ,{0, KACT_None,  0 } // key # 9
};
```

Comment: Which line does it complain about?  Your code looks fine, assuming all of those symbols are available.

Comment: I don't see any problem with it, would it not be the casts to `void*`. What type is your "Link"? If it is `void*` you would not have to cast. If it is of a different type and your variables are of a different one , this design is questionable.

Comment: You need to show the declarations of the `KACT_*` and `SCRN_*` identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your compiler may not be using C99 mode. This type of initialization should be fine with C99 mode enabled.